# better way to use onSubmit when trying to push object in to an array

Tags: reactjs, submit, state

i'm trying to write a more efficient way to set state an array with a new object, my state is this:

```
 state = {
    names: [],
    tempName: {
      name: '',
      mail: ''
    }
  };
```

Im using on submit like so:

```
 onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputs = [...this.state.names, this.state.tempName];
    const tempName = { name: '', mail: ''};
    this.setState({ inputs, tempInput });

};
```

and I was hoping to do something shorter like this:

```
    onSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { tempName } = this.state.tempName;
      this.setState(curr => ({
       names: [{ ...curr.names, tempName }]
    }));
  };
```

but all I get is a reference to the object inside the array, is there a better way to do it then the one stated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) on an object to copy its enumerable properties onto a new object.

```
onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState(currentState => ({
    names: [...currentState.names, {...currentState.tempName}],
    tempName: {
      name: '',
      mail: ''
    }
  }));
};
```